# Facebook Like button does not work on site but FB URL Linter not reporting errors

Tags: javascript, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

No idea why Facebook like button isn't working on this site: http://allisonchow.com

[image: Screenshot of FB like button error]

Clicking on the `error` link in error (shown in above screenshot) I get this error:

[image: FB error]

I've triple checked it through Facebook URL Linter ([https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fallisonchow.com](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://allisonchow.com)) and it reports that there are no errors.  I've tried the HTML5, XFBML as well as IFRAME versions of the button with no luck.

**Other details:**

FB URL linter sometimes reports warnings that `og:url` and `og:title` are not "explicitly provided":

```
The og:url property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can 
be inferred from other tags.

The og:title property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can 
be inferred from other tags.
```

However, the weird thing is that both these OpenGraph tags are specified in my code. FB Linter even confirms it by showing further down the same page:

[image: Screenshot of FB URL Linter]

Additionally, the linter will occassionally give this warning as well:

```
The og:locale property should be explicitly provided, even if a 
value can be inferred from other tags.
```

But again, if I reload the linter and run the URL through it again, the warnings will periodically appear and disappear. Ugh.

Unfortunately when a Like button doesn't work, if the Linter doesn't report errors I find it extremely hard to debug!

I must be missing something obvious so would love some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a facebook bug.
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/270137973042283

Comment: Yep that was it. Looks like it's fixed at least for my site (for now).